# Python constructor parameters order in datetime class

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, constructor

I want to wrap a `datetime` class with `DayTime` which would represent only 24 hours of a day.

This is my wrap:

```
class DayTime(datetime):
    def __init__(self, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0):
        super(DayTime, self).__init__(0, 0, 0, hour, minute, second, microsecond)
```

But when I write the test for it:

```
def test_day_time_object(self):
    time = DayTime(1, 2, 3, 4)

    self.assertEqual(time.year, 0)
    self.assertEqual(time.month, 0)
    self.assertEqual(time.day, 0)
    self.assertEqual(time.hour, 1)
    self.assertEqual(time.minute, 2)
    self.assertEqual(time.second, 3)
    self.assertEqual(time.microsecond, 4)
```

I get

> AssertionError: 1 != 0

It appears that the `year` is `1`, `month` is `2`, `day` is `3` and `hour` is `4`.
How to explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

First, the 'oldest' datetime you can construct is:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> dt.datetime.min
datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

You need to use `__new__` instead of `__init__`, because the 'orginal' class has no `__init__` method:

```
class DayTime(dt.datetime):
    def __new__(cls, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0):
        return super().__new__(cls, 1, 1, 1, hour, minute, second, microsecond, tzinfo= None)


d1 = DayTime(1,2,3,4)
print(d1)

d2 = DayTime(4,3,2,1)
print(d2)
```

returns:

```
0001-01-01 01:02:03.000004
0001-01-01 04:03:02.000001
```

Comment: Thanks.
I would like to ask one more thing, maybe there is a class that represents just day ?

Comment: There is a [date](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects) object